# break data returned from foreach function into seperate div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

This is my particular section of a razor view page which is displaying a partialview in a div.

```
  <section class="middle-section peoplePageList defaultPage listOfPeople clearfix">
    <div class="peopleList">
      <div class="listItem">
         @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ProfileListPartial", Model); }
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**My problem is i want to display data from this partial view in every seperate div. means if data of 10 peoples is received then 10 div should be created with class listItem.** I am not great at designing but problem is, i have to do it in any way.

The _ProfileListPartial razor page is something like this:

```
@model App.Models.PeopleModel

 <div class="peopleList" data-bind="visible: profiles().length > 0, foreach: profiles">
  <div class="media-body">
   <a class="btn pull-right" data-bind="visible: !isFollowed && !isOwnProfile, attr: { href: followAction }">Follow</a>
   <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-bind="visible: isFollowed && !isOwnProfile, attr: { href: unfollowAction }">Unfollow</a>
   <em data-bind="text: name"></em> 
   </div>
  </div>
```

here, as u can see in first line **foreach: profiles** , it returns multiple profiles from knockout function with name, image, button, id and other stuff.

My problem is when it renders on view page, all these get combined into single div not in multiple divs. May be, it will be possible to break data in seperate div through javascript.
please suggest me something how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout's `foreach` merely repeats the tags it contains for each item in the list. Therefore, if you want each wrapped in a div with a particular class, that just needs to be contained within. For example:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: profiles">
    <div class="listItem">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have got it resolved yesterday by myself btw thnx for the answer @Chris Pratt